# cascade save in hibernate, foregin key is saved as null

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class as follows

```
class A{
 Set<B> = new HashSet<B>();

}

class B{
  A a;

}
```

Now primary key of A is autogenerated so i cant set it before in A or B.B has inverse mapping of A.And A object within B  is null originally.
This maps to 2 tables A and B in DB.Now if i have a object A whose Set contains 2 records then when i save object A then 2 records gets created in B.Now my code is working fine.But when i see the recods in B i find foreign key corresponding to A is blank.How come?

```
TABLE B structure
BId Aid Bname
```

//Aid is foreign key to A tablles primary key and Aid is stored as null, why so?I want that the Aid should be automatically stored in B

Comment: Based on the info you provided, Joël's answer sounds right on target. If this isn't the problem, provide more detail, like some sample code and mapping files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to correctly set both side of the relation**

```
parentA.getBChilds().add(childB);  
childB.setParentA(parentA); <-- Important see link below working bi
```

You can create a link management methods in the parent to correctly set both sides.

```
public class ParentA
{
...    
public void addChildB(B pChild)
{
    this.childsB.add(pChild);
    pChild.setParentA( this );
}    
...
}
```

**Set the 'inverse' attribute to true on the collection relation**

```
<set name="bChilds" inverse="true">
    <key column="bID"/>
    <one-to-many class="childB"/>
</set>
```

Maybe you're mixing between inverse and cascade. For a good explanation you can read this blog entry on the hibernate inverse attribute [Hibernates bizarre interpretation of inverse ;)](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/colinyates/entry/hibernates_bizzare_interpretation/) and this hibernate doc on [Working bi-directional links](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir)

Comment: that saved alot of time!